# Keyboard Shortcuts for JAWS with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jaws-screen-reader

What keyboard shortcut can be used to go to the previous page (Go Back) in JAWS with IE. Also keyboard shortcut to open a link in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JAWS running to use these shortcuts.

- **Go back** - Alt+LeftArrow
- **Open link in new tab** - Tab to link, Shift+F10 (to get context menu), arrow down to 'open in new tab'